# Sliding banner from the top

Tags: joomla, banner, sliding

In my joomla site I need a banner that is sliding from the top of the page.
Whole page should go down, when banner is sliding.
I made something like this, but the site don't do down:

html:

```
<div id="module">
    <img src="http://preart.kylos.pl/przykladowy-banner.jpg" alt="headerContact"> 
</div> 
<div id="whole-page">Whole page</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function slide(){
    $("#module").delay(1000).animate({
        "top":"10px"
    },1000);
}
    slide();
});
```

css:

```
#module { 
top: -200px;
position: fixed;
}

#whole-page { 
width: 100%; 
height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Elfiszcze/69x8dofu/1/

How can I achive this? Maybe there is a ready solution for joomla?

Comment: Use slide down instead of animate and don't apply css.

Comment: Could You please give me an example?